# equivalent code in php

Tags: php, javascript, loops

there is possible make something like this in php ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
     $("#one"+i).html("PHP");
};
</script>
```

basically, append html content to a div.

tnaks

Comment: Are you asking use to convert that script for you? Do you have a specific question or just trying to offload work?

Comment: my question is about append content to a div in php. I know that i can make it in JS but not in php

Comment: "*I know that i can make it in JS but not in php*" - Specifically, why not. What's giving you trouble. The loop? Printing content? Finding dom elements? Determining where this logic should go in an existing php stack? I'd love to know why 4 people thought your comment was 'great' when it contained the same wording as your question.

Comment: I agree with @Mike. This question is far too vague as evidenced by the myriad of divergent answers. Please read [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this plugin out. It will allow you to search HTML strings just like jQuery and modify it. I have used it before and it's pretty simple to use and understand.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a standard set of [DOM tools](http://php.net/DOM/). You would need to build a DOM, manipulate it, then output it rather instead of using PHP as a template language.

Comment: PHP _is_ a template language. Why not use it as such?

Comment: This is just a guess. We have no idea where the OP expects this logic to go. During generation of this page? Post-processing via dom manipulation? Answers to this question are going to be all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
     echo '<div id="#one'.$i.'">PHP</div>';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), it's a serverside implementation of jquery.

Answer (score -1):

PHP runs on the server and builds the page that this javascript is running on. Essentially what you're trying to do is get a car factory to change the radio station presets on your car, but only on your car.

The proper solution in PHP is to output your `PHP` text as it's building those divs.

```
<div id="one1">
<?php echo 'PHP' ?>
</div>

<div id="one2">
<?php echo 'PHP' ?>
</div>

etc...
```

Reaching 'back' into what it's already built is very inefficient.